# Is a complement of the union of all open first category subsets a Baire's space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $P$ be the union of all open subsets of $X$ which are of the first category. By the Banach category theorem $P$ is of the first category. Is a closed subspace $X\setminus P$ of $X$, as a topological space, a Baire's space, i.e. is each nonempty open subset in $X\setminus P$ of the second category?

Edit.

We assume additionally that $X\setminus P$ is not empty.

Thanks

Comment: $X\setminus P$ can be empty: consider the space of rationals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the additional assumption that $X\setminus P\ne\varnothing$, the result is true. Let $Y=X\setminus P$. Let $U$ be a non-empty set open in $Y$, and suppose that $U$ is meagre. Then $U=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$, where the sets $A_n$ are nowhere dense subsets of $Y$. $Y$ is closed in $X$, so $\operatorname{cl}_YA_n=\operatorname{cl}_XA_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Moreover, $\operatorname{int}_XA\subseteq\operatorname{int}_YA$ for every $A\subseteq Y$, so

$$\operatorname{int}_X\operatorname{cl}_XA_n\subseteq\operatorname{int}_Y\operatorname{cl}_YA_n=\varnothing$$

for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and $U$ is meagre in $X$ as well. But then $U\cup P=P$, which is absurd. Thus, no non-empty open subset of $Y$ is meagre in $Y$.

Comment: Maybe it is not essential,  but open set $U$  in $Y$ need not be open in $X$ and we don't know if $U \subset P$.

Comment: @Richard: I didn’t give enough explanation at the end: $U=V\setminus P$ for some open $V$ in $X$, so $U\cup P$ is open and meagre in $X$ and therefore equal to $P$, and $U\subseteq P$.

Comment: @Richard: You’re very welcome.